# What's the difference between these two Chronometer implementations?

Tags: android

I've been playing around with Android Studio and I'm trying to implement a simple chronometer with the Chronometer widget. First I tried this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Chronometer chrono;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startChrono(View view) {
        chrono.start();
    }

    public void stopChrono(View view) {
        chrono.stop();
    }
}
```

But when I used it, whenever I pressed the Start button, it would crash the app. Then I found this implementation online:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Chronometer chrono;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startChrono(View view) {
        ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer)).start();
    }

    public void stopChrono(View view) {
        ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer)).start();
    }
}
```

This one works though, can anyone point out the differences between creating the Chronometer object in onCreate as opposed to what the second block of code does?

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4020)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Chronometer.start()' on a null object reference
            at com.example.mykongee.testchronometer.MainActivity.startChrono(MainActivity.java:22)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Downvote because `it would crash the app` with out posting a stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You can not call `findViewById` before you call `setContentLayout`, because there is no view to find.

You app would have crashed with a `NullPointerException` because chrono was null.

In your first example, try swapping these two lines, and it will work the same as the second

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
```

In the future, do not simply say `it didnt work`, Android provides an amazong `LogCat` that tells you pretty much EXACTLY what the problem is.
If you can not decode the error yourself, then post the stacktrace provided by logcat.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be more careful with my wording and will be sure to provide proper error documentation in the future.

Comment: Glad to help, and Happy Coding :) If you edit your original question to provide the stacktrace of the failure, I can change my vote on your question.

Comment: Done! Ah I see now, it pointed out the NullPointerException. I'll make a habit of checking the logcat from now on, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first one you are first trying to get a reference to chrono, then you are setting your layout. The thing is, you can't get a reference without setting the layout first (can't find what isn't there...)

false:

```
    chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

correct:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
```

In the second example you are setting the layout, then on button press you find the reference, so everything is ok.